# Karaf start results Insufficient credentials

Tags: java, apache-karaf, karaf

i have a problem with Apache-Karaf 3.0.0 on Ubuntu
I want to start a bundle with the command "start". But i get the follow error:

> Error executing command: Insufficient credentials.

Also "start --help" prompt this error.

The command "list" and "list --help" works perfect.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Karaf 3.0 we introduced the role based authentication for commands and JMX. So you likely didn't log into Karaf using any credentials. If you want to use a "restricted" command like stoping starting a bundle you either have to log-in using the right credentials, or need to disable the authentication for this command. To do so edit the etc/org.apache.karaf.commands.acl.bundle.cfg configuration.

```
start[/.*[-][f].*/] = admin
start = manager
stop[/.*[-][f].*/] = admin
stop = manager
```

Right now the default behavior is to have admin rights for start -f (force) where start is open to any "manager". So you have to change the start/stop command to be available for manager also.